# How do I detect which multiple old versions of directx are installed at the same time?

Tags: windows, windows-10, directx

`dxdiag` says I have directx 12 installed. But some video games I want to play use directx 8 and 9 and the cd rom comes with the directx installer for the old versions. But if it did get installed, how do I check if the old versions have been installed?

I need multiple versions to be installed at the same time and to be able to check the existence of older versions being installed. `Dxdiag` only shows the latest version of 12.

[image: run dxdiag directx diagnostics]

[image: dxdiag directx version installed]

Comment: `Multiple versions of DX 9 should not be installed` No that's not what I meant. I meant installing both version 8 and 9 at the same time.

Comment: So I suppose it’s good that the CD-ROM I have with me has the Installer for directx 8 and 9 on it. ;) That would make me lucky. So now I’ve Installed them both from the cd, how do I check it’s installed?

Answer (score 0):

> I need multiple versions to be installed at the same time and to be able to check the existence of older versions being installed. Dxdiag only shows the latest version of 12.

DirectX 12 is built into Windows 10, it cannot be installed separately, nor could it be uninstalled.  By having the current version of Windows 10 installed you have the capability of running (DirectX 9.0, DirectX 10.0, DirectX 11, and DirectX 12) software.

Source: [Feature support for feature levels 12_2 through 9_3](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-devices-downlevel-intro)

> But some video games I want to play use DirectX 8 and 9 and the cdrom comes with the DirectX installer for the old versions.

DirectX 12 is backward compatible with DirectX 9.0c provided the author of the application targets the DirectX 9 feature level of DirectX 12 instead of literally targeting DirectX 9.

Since the last DirectX 9 release is backward compatible with previous versions you should only need the most recent version released.  Microsoft has taken down all versions of DirectX 9.  So hopefully, the application you want to use provided the DirectX 9.0c End-User Runtime or you might have some compatibility issues.

> But if it did get installed, how do I check if the old versions have been installed?  So now I’ve Installed them both from the cd, how do I check it’s installed?

If DirectX 9.0c Runtime is installed it would be displayed in `Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features` on any support version of Windows.  Since DirectX 12 is a  feature of Windows 10, and it cannot be installed, it won't be listed in Programs and Features.

The exact version of DirectX 12 you will have is entirely based on the version of Windows 10 you have installed.  DirectX 12 backward capability is handled through [feature levels](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3dcommon/ne-d3dcommon-d3d_feature_level) but an application must specifically target DirectX 12 and specify the feature level within their application instead of targeting DirectX 9.0c specifically.

| Version | Version | Windows Version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 10.00.10240.16384 | Windows 10 (1507) |
| 12 | 10.00.15063.0000 | Windows 10 (1703) |
| 12 | 10.00.17763.0000 | Windows 7 |
| 12 | 10.00.17763.0001 | Windows 10 (1809) |
| 12 | 10.00.18362.0116 | Windows 10 (1903) |
| 12 (Ultimate) | NA | Windows 10 20H1 |

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm answering an old question, but since no answer has been accepted yet, I'll try to give mine.
I'm a big fan of classics too, and so far have DirectX 9 to 12 installed in my Windows 11.
It's okay to have them all installed, they'll just wasting space if not needed.
How you know if old DirectX installation is successful? Simplest way is by having your classic game running.
Though many sources would mention that newer directX has backward support for older ones, most games are coded to look for certain file names to indicate the presence of needed DirectX libraries. For example DirectX 9 libraries would contain *d3dx9* within the file, 10 would be *d3dx10* and so on.
So, install away...

Comment: Look at this video of me installing a video game that runs on DirectX 8.1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6W--NA76qU https://i.imgur.com/FQvXWuk.jpg So now you can see the video of me installing the video game which should have also instead DirectX 8.1, how can I check if it's been installed? Just playing the video game to see if it works, that doesn't count.

Comment: each and every app and games that utilizes DirectX looks for a specific file on windows system folder which will they then utilize. If the respective file doesn't exist it WILL NOT work, if the file exist but other files that it depends on doesn't exist it WILL NOT work also. As simple as that. Of course you could always run dxdiag.exe to see what your latest installed DirectX version is (assuming you are running the latest dxdiag), but it will not show other, older, version you have installed.

Comment: Microsoft has recently updated it's DX Library collection to allow you to download the whole legacy series of DirectX up to the latest version. 
Here's the direct link [from Microsoft Download][1]


  [1]: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35